# Нужно ли корректировать верстку так, чтобы при масштабировании нигде ничего не выпирало?

Tags: html, css, sass, scss

Нужно ли вообще корректировать верстку так, чтоб при масштабировании нигде ничего не выпирало и тд? 
Вот как выглядит отверстанная часть на 100%:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тоже отверстанная часть, но с двойным масштабом (200%):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите, заголовок заплыл под квадрат.

Скажите, это вообще важно? Или это ерунда? А то мне не хватает фундаментальных знаний в этой сфере...

Comment: Для того что бы такого не было надо абсолютно все размеры указывать в еденицах vw, vh, тогда при увеличении ничего не будет меняться. Но не всегда удобно и актуально задавать все размеры с помощью этих едениц. Насколько же это важно, 
конечно же зависит от требований заказчика, но я бы сказал что над этим нужно заморачиваться в последнюю очередь. Но с другой стороны избавиться от этого, как я уже сказал, в не очень усложненной вёрстке, как ваша, достаточно просто. Уже отвечал на подобный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1080055/320859. Надеюсь вам поможет.

Answer (score 8):

> нужно ли вообще корректировать верстку так, чтоб при масштабировании
>   нигде ничего не выпирало и тд?

Отвечаю на ваш вопрос. Если вы хотите, чтобы все пользователи видели качественно выполненную вами работу и ваш сайт можно было просматривать на самых разных устройствах, независимо от разрешения и формата экрана, будь то пк, ноутбук, планшет, смартфон или любое другое устройство, то, наверное, нужно. Адаптивный дизайн является одним из главных показателей качества вашего сайта, обеспечивающий отличное его восприятие на различных устройствах, так как в настоящее время существует множество таких устройств, которыми люди пользуются. Все эти устройства различаются размером экрана, разрешением и, соответственно, тем, как может отображаться на этих устройствах ваш сайт. Поэтому очень важно, чтобы ваш сайт хорошо смотрелся и правильно отображался, как это вами было задумано при его создании, у любого из пользователей, независимо от того, какое устройство он использует.

А [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079881/html-css-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0/1079904#1079904) всё адаптивно. Повторюсь:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrp {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.kwad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.kwad span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
h1 {
font-size: 5vw;
padding: 30px;
color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrp"><img src="https://mtdata.ru/u22/photoDCC4/20414722554-0/original.jpg"></div>
  <div class="wrp"><h1>Пушкин</h1></div>
  <div class="kwad">01<br><span>Пушкин</span></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrp"><h1>Пушкин Здесь много много очень много Пушкина</h1></div>
  <div class="wrp"><img src="https://cdn.cadelta.ru/media/articles/id5431/cover.jpg"></div>
  <div class="kwad">01<br><span>Пушкин</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ладно показываю - можете проверять на мобилах и где угодно

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.marker {
  position: relative;
}

.unit {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(100% - 25px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.reverse {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.reverse .unit {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(0% - 25px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 562px) {
  .unit {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  .item h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .item p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 396px) {
  .unit {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: calc(50% - 15px);
    left: calc(100% - 15px);
  }
  .item h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .item p {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item marker">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="">
    <div class="unit">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>lorem ipsum</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br> consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Laboriosam ex totam <br> doloremque eos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="items reverse">
  <div class="item marker">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="">
    <div class="unit">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>lorem ipsum</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br> consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Laboriosam ex totam <br> doloremque eos.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
```